# Display that User Current Location as the value of the Textbox

Tags: php, html, google-maps

I have here a  codes that displays the current location of the user, this codes is already working. My problem is how to put the id "#location" as the value for my textbox in html form so that the current location will put in a textbox form.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation);
    } else { 
        $('#location').html('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
    }
});

function showLocation(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'../geo/getLocation.php',
        data:'latitude='+latitude+'&longitude='+longitude,
        success:function(msg){
            if(msg){
               $("#location").html(msg);
            }else{
                $("#location").html('Not Available');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
Location: <input id="location" type="text" value="" size="50">
<br>
```

[image]

Comment: What is the problem? What does your ajax request return as response? Did you debug at all?

Comment: My codes is already working Sir it shows the current location of the user. My problem is how to put the id #location as a value for my html textbox form so that the current location will go to textbox form.

Comment: Why did you revert my correction of your question? Do you really think "a codes" is correct English!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ajax request works correctly (we don't know what kind of data it returns), when the problem is in wrong choice of method.
Use `.val()` instead of `.html()` because you can't insert html inside `input`.

```
if (msg) {
  $("#location").val(msg);
} else {
  $("#location").val('Not Available');
}
```

Comment: My codes is already working Sir it shows the current location of the user. My problem is how to put the id #location as a value for my html textbox form so that the current location will go to textbox form.

Comment: As I said, use `.val()` instead of `.html()`.

Comment: Thank you Sir, I replace it as you've said and now it's working.

Comment: You're welcome. If everything's okay, you can check this answer to show that the question is closed.